Initializing an mpz_t variable with a static function in between translation units
I am writing a cryptographic program for my bachelor's. I've been uzing an mpz_t variable for exponentiation with the PBC library.
Currently, to avoid running mpz_init on every exponentiation, I only run mpz_init(mpz_a); once at the start of the program. The inits.c file contains the function
void pairing_setup(void) {
    ...
    exponent_init();
}

Which is run once before any exponentiation takes place.
The exponent_init() function is contained in the exponents.h header file, and is as follows:
static inline void exponent_init(void) { mpz_init(mpz_a); }

extern mpz_t mpz_a; is declared inside that same header file.
Now the question is. Are the following functions declared in the exponents.c file valid, or might they result in undefined behavior? If not, can I declare mpz_a as static as well?
mpz_t mpz_a;

void set_a(long long v) {
    ...
    mpz_set_si(mpz_a, v);
    ...
}

element_t *shift(element_t *element, long long value) {
    set_a(value);
    element_pow_mpz(*element, *element, mpz_a);
    return element;
}

Not running mpz_init() altogether did not cause the program to break. So I can't debug whether it ran correctly or not.
